# Propositional logic and combinatorics: Counting equivalent formulae that satisfy a condition

Tags: combinatorics, logic, propositional-calculus

Consider splitting the set of all the propositional formulae on $n \ge 5$ variables $x_1, \dots x_n$ in equivalence classes such that in each class there are formulae that are equivalent, namely $\psi \equiv \varphi$. How many of them contain formulae $\psi$ such that $ [(x_1 \to x_2) \wedge x_3 \wedge x_4 \wedge x_5 ] \to \psi$?

I have arrived to a result: $2^{2^n - 24 }$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

If I understand you correctly, you're asking how many *Boolean functions* of $n$ variables there are such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=1$ whenever $(x_1\to x_2)\land x_3\land x_4\land x_5$ is $1$.

If we're filling in a truth table with $2^n$ rows, this condition fixes the value of $3$ rows out of every group of $32$ (where a "group" is a set of rows that agree on the values of $x_6, x_7, \ldots$).

This leaves $(32-3)2^{n-5}$ rows where we can choose the output freely, so there will be
$$ 2^{29\cdot 2^{n-5}} $$
qualifying Boolean functions (i.e. equivalence classes of formulas).